# What ways do one have to find the problems that are behing the symptoms?

Tags: coding-style

I'm a bad programmer. I'm absolutely certain of that. I have a lot to get better, but now, I'm concerned with the time I spend fixing programming issues that I create for myself (because I'm a bad programmer).

I find myself commonly having three problems:

1) `Syntax problems`; (that I can fix with some more practice). - less time consuming;

2) `Logical problems`; (that I can fix with more tought and practice). - a lot of time consuming;

3) `Silent Symptoms problems`; (that get me stuck and I can't progress).

The third problem is indeed an issue, because in face of some symptoms (that don't throw any  error that "jumps into our eyes"), I can't identify what is the problem our problems that are behind those symptoms.

For example:
I'm now having an issue related to a gallery. The gallery is functional, but some of their fixtures don't work. I can't find the reason for that. I see the symptoms, I've lost two days trying to find/provoke issues in order to find where the problem is. No luck. I can't even formulate a question to place here at SO.

I need your help to point me out, what kind of "techniques"/"ways" do one have, in order to discovered silent Symptoms and find the related problem (so that we can THEN find the solution).

Can anyone please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't the only one who is having these kind of problems (good or bad programmer aside). Because I often program in a very object oriented way I find it quite easy to narrow the problem down to a specific package (or package relation).

From there on I try to get closer to the actual problem. Does the sentence I wrote here do exactly as I think it does and if not how can I change it to work in the way I wanted.

Being able to estimate where the silent symptoms occur plays a huge role in solving them I believe.